# Websphere 7 error: A WSDL Definition could not be generated for the implementation class

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, websphere-7

Excuse me for my english

I have an application that uses **jax-ws** and **spring**, it work on tomcat fine, but i should deploy it on **Websphere 7**.

WAS7 throws the following exception:

> 00000027 WSModuleDescr E   WSWS7027E: JAX-WS Service Descriptions could not be correctly built because of the following error:
>   javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: WSWS7054E: The Web Services
>   Description Language (WSDL) file could not be generated for the
>   com.foo.MyEndpoint Web service implementation class because of the
>   following error: java.lang.Exception: A WSDL Definition could not be
>   generated for the implementation class: com.foo.MyEndpoint    at
>   com.ibm.ws.websvcs.wsdl.WASWSDLGenerator.generateWsdl(WASWSDLGenerator.java:230)

my endpoint classes are:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.foo.MyService", targetNamespace = "http://www.foo.com/xsd")
public class MyEndpoint  implements MyService
{
...
}
```

and interface is:

```
@WebService(portName = "MyPort", serviceName = "MyService", 
  targetNamespace = "http://www.foo.com/xsd")
public interface MyService
{
...
}
```

Any idea what can cause that problem? How to check, what **exactly** is wrong here? The error message is too vague...

Comment: I think it is enviroment issue. I googled and found [these](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21590404) [issues](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM20042).

Comment: I saw this page before, our was administrator said, these Fix Packs already installed on was.

Comment: Are there any other error messages in the logs that hint at the problem?  If not, I recommend opening a PMR with IBM; the WSWS7027E error message is inscrutible.

Answer (score 2):

I figure out that, i changed my classes like the following and it works.

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://www.foo.com/xsd")
public interface MyService
{
...
}
```

and endpoint class:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.foo.MyService", targetNamespace = "http://www.foo.com/xsd")
public class MyEndpoint  implements MyService
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon the same problem but with a different root cause. Hope this will save someone a headache in the future:

I used a custom annotation (@MyAnnotation) in classes that were used inside an EAR deployment. This produced the abovementioned error while deploying. After getting rid of the annotations, the error disappeared.